# Запятую нужно ставить перед или после потому?

Tags: пунктуация

Совмневаюсь в постановке запятой после **потому**. *Самая богатая страна в мире потому, что половину её населения составляют потомки сбежавших из Европы кассиров.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В вашем случае запятая может стоять как перед, так и после *потому*. Зависит от того, падает на это слово логическое ударение или нет.
[Подробнее](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/punctum-attach3).